# Работа с хуками

Tags: drupal, php

Есть хук:

```
function upc_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['cart/payment-sent/upc-connect'] = array(
        'title' => 'Статус платежа',
        'page callback' => 'upc_checkout_payment',
        'page arguments' => array($_POST['Signature']),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Вопрос: в качестве колбек функции (*page callback*) следует указывать только внутренние функции api друпала или можно любые, в том числе самописные?

P.s. функция *upc_checkout_payment* определена в тоже файле что и *upc_menu*.

Comment: можно и **самописные**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любые. Это просто функция, которую можно вызвать внутри вашего сайта. То есть, не забудте указать подключаемый файл.